# How to add radio button in drupal profile page

Tags: 7, users

I want to get more info from my users when they register.
With the standard profile.module I have the following options:

- single-line textfield
- multi-line textfield
- checkbox
- list selection
- freeform list
- URL
- date

But I want radio buttons to select 1 option from multiple options.
This can be done with list selection, but I prefer radio buttons.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using the [Profile Checkboxes](http://drupal.org/project/profile_checkboxes) module, you can be able to add radio buttons in the Drupal profile page.

1. Download the Profile Checkboxes module, and install it.
2. If you need to create a radio buttons field, click "List selection" in "Add new field."
3. In that page, you will find the "Selection options" option with a text area field. Enter the radio button details here. For example, if you are adding the gender, enter "Male" and in next line enter "Female."
4. Now, at the bottom of the page you will find the "Profile checkboxes" tab.
5. There you select the "Radio buttons (single choice)" and save.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to customise the user profile / registration pages I recommend using the [Content Profile](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_profile) module. Some more details about it (from its project page):

> This module builds user profiles as content (aka nodes), which opens the opportunity to use all the powerful modules for content for user profiles too, e.g. the Content Construction Kit (CCK). It's intended to be simple and useful, but extensible by further modules.
>
> Content profiles can be restricted to certain roles; the module also supports separate content profiles for different roles.

It allows you to use CCK fields on both user profiles and registration pages. You can use Radio boxes easily along with all the other great features provided by CCK.

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 7 you must enable the Option module, which is a separate core module that will enable these fields. It's a change in the way things were done in drupal 6.

Comment: The Profile module doesn't use any fields provided through the field API, and the OP said to be using that module.